# Why is it possible to identify a language without hearing the words?

Tags: phonology

I have noticed that often while walking in the street in a foreign country, I will be able to recognize that someone nearby is speaking a language I'm familiar with without actually being able to make out the words. This effect is most pronounced for my mothertongue, where sometimes just hearing what seems to be an onomatopeic sound will be enough. Is there a basis for this phenomenon ? Do languages have a sort of frequency signature that we can immediately identify ?

Comment: Phonology. I actually wrote a neural net AI in AI class that identified languages based on the sequence of letters used (to make it interesting I only used the Roman alphabet), using 50 neurons per language. It had an accuracy in the 90-95% range.

Comment: Well, I may have misinterpreted your question. If you can't even hear the sounds, prosody can still give you a lot of information. I've noticed the same thing: I can identify some languages through walls, with heavy muffling and an almost complete inability to hear the individual sounds.

Comment: +1 this is an excellent question -- in fact, with even limited exposure, it's not hard to identify languages you don't even know a word of.

Comment: @ Justin Olbrantz: I meant no being able to distinguish the individual words while still hearing the sound of the language being spoken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Languages can often be distinguished based on prosodic information alone. Studies show that a newborn infant can distinguish different languages, provided the languages being compared are prosodically different enough from one another. A newborn is also predisposed to recognize her mother's native language.

In one study (Nazzi, Bertoncini, and Mehler 1998), French newborns could distinguish English from Japanese and English/Dutch from Italian/Spanish, but not English from Dutch or Italian from Spanish.

The theory is that prosodic information, but not segmental information, can be perceived from inside the womb.

Nazzi, T., Bertoncini, J., and Mehler, J. (1998). *Language discrimination by newborns: toward an understanding of the role of rhythm.* Journal of Experimental Psychology 24(3) 756-766.